# SUMIF using named array consisting of non-adjacent columns

Tags: excel

Good morning!

I am trying to create a dynamic SUMIF by using a named array containing data in non-adjancent columns.

The situation is as follows:

1. I have a file with monthly data, where the columns are labelled as:

**Jan 2010, Feb 2010,** (...)**, Dec 2010**, FY 2010 (...) **Jan 2020, Feb 2020,** (...), **Dec 2020**, FY 2020

2. I want to sum only the monthly data (**Jan 2010, Feb 2010**... **Dec 2010, Jan 2011, Feb 2011**, etc) and exclude the data in the FY column (FY 2010, FY 2011, etc etc)
3. I have named the array of monthly data that interests me as a range ("relevant_monthly_data")
4. I am looking at individual rows of data that interest me ("country_range"). Note that the country_range consists of only one column with all the countries. It has the same number of rows as "relevant_monthly_data".
5. The formula that I am using only works for the first set of adjacent columns (Jan-Dec 2010), but doesn't capture Jan-Dec 2011, 2012... all the way through to 2020 even though they are all part of the named array).

=SUM(INDEX(relevant_monthly_data,MATCH("Guatemala",country_range,0),))

Could you please help me?

I am sure it is a simple question, but I somehow cannot figure out how to sum this range beyond 2010 monthly entries...

Thank you in advance for your help!

Comment: I think `SUMPRODUCT()` will help.

Comment: How would I be able to go about it with SUMPRODUCT? I get the same issue with both functions :-( The problem really is that there are non-adjacent columns inside the named array, and so the functions only pick up the initial columns before the first break :-(

Comment: An example of your data would be helpful, as would knowledge of your version of Excel. Also, are the date column headers text strings or formatted dates?